# vba excel onclick: javascript:PostBackNoAjax

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I am trying to trigger from VBA excel a javascript link that should open windows dialogue "do you want to open, save or close the file" in order to download a pdf file. 
But I don't know how to tell VBA to trigger this event on that link because I cannot find any ID or name of the element:

This is the code I have.I am not expert of JavaScript at all and I tried different solutions I found on the web using below two ctl00 as id but I failed. 
Could you please help me to trigger the click event of the link?

```
<td><a onclick="javascript:PostBackNoAjax(this,event,'ctl00_cRadAjaxSettings_RadAjaxManager1');"     
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataGridDocuments$ctl03$ctl00','')">10167666</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try let explorer navigate to the link directly

```
objIE.navigate "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataGridDocuments$ctl03$ctl00','')"
```